# Are there any other (not complex) ways to make a number inverse?

Tags: functions

The four main ones that I've gotten myself are:

1a. $x - (2x)$

1b. $(-2x) + x$

1c. $-1*x$

1d. $x/-1$

I'm in the 6th grade, so some of the more complex ways are welcome, but i probably won't understand it.

edit: yeah this question was stupid

Comment: The title only says "into **a** negative number", so $x-3x$ also works. Or do you only want $f(x)=-x$? Then this is the only one. Writing $-x=x-2x$ doesn't matter. You could write arbitrary expressions for $-x$, say $-x=4x-5x$ etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am not sure if a 6th grader understands function notation.

Comment: @MathGeek I am not sure this is a 6th grader (often different).

Comment: To be honest, a 6th grader shouldn't be on Math SE or any SE since you must be 13 or over

Comment: Really? I had no idea. I might have to go inactive for a year if this is true.

Comment: @extremistpolyhedron  It's not really clear what you are asking, and I think it's likely that guessing will just be confusing.  I suggest talking to your teacher or to someone else who knows you and who knows a little math.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to convert a positive integer to its negative equivalent. You seem to have covered all the methods of doing so. However, if we want to convert a positive integer $x$ to its negative counterpart, then $nx - (n+1)x, n \in \mathbb{N}$ would be another method.

Comment: Are you assuming $X = x$?

Comment: There's a difference?

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer Yes $X=x$

Comment: @extremistpolyhedron Thank you for accepting! If you like this answer, try upvoting it.

Comment: yw i guess. Also, sorry for not clarifying, seems like the idea of saying "inverse counterpart" flew right over my head.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you for pointing that out. I have now removed that whole thing about $nx -2nx$. I do make silly mistakes from time to time.

Comment: $nx - (n+1)x, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I know what you mean but are they really all?

Comment: @NaN Thank you for bringing this up. I was going to say that but I was wondering if a 6th grader would understand it. I have added it now though.

Comment: @MathGeek I didn't mean to be a smart arse, just thought I would add it for some banter :)

Comment: @NaN It's ok, I didn't think you were acting like a smart ----.